# Orthographic projection technical drawing

Tags: technical-drawing

My professor asked me to make the orthographic projection of this object with the third angle rule, but the object has an oblique/slanted surface. Does it require an auxiliary view too?

[image: 1]

Comment: which feature would require an auxiliary view, and why?

Comment: go with your instinct ... after all, it is an assignment that you should be doing without someone else telling you what to do ... just ask yourself `does an auxiliary view add new information?`

Comment: Think of technical drawing like writing a report. Its natural language, you dont have to always use the same construction. If you feel that two views is enough then it probably is. You could use a auxiliary view, cutaway or a partial cutaway...

Comment: Being a nit picker for wording, the question in the picture states "Draw **AN** orthographic projection..." as oppose to "Draw **the** orthographic...".  So to me its pick a single view and draw it, though if it is from a practice book, I would draw all the orthographic views I could as a matter of practice.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it require an auxiliary view too?

I would think yes to make the dimensions of the dovetail slot clear.